# Powershell executed from C# to manage ActiveDirectory groups

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to run a simple query in our AD from a program in C#, but I always get a "Unable to contact the server" error that I don't understand. I think it might be related in some rights that I'm missing but can't figure out or find which rights I need.

This is the powershell command

```
Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity "GrpLanguageFrench" -Members "MazMa" -Confirm:$false
```

This is the C# code

```
InitialSessionState iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault();
string[] modules = { "activedirectory" };
iss.ImportPSModule(modules);


//Create PowerShell runspace
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
runspace.Open();

Pipeline pipeline1 = runspace.CreatePipeline();
Command myCommandR1 = new Command("Remove-ADGroupMember");

myCommandR1.Parameters.Add("Identity", "GrpLanguageFrench");       
myCommandR1.Parameters.Add("Members", "MazMa");
myCommandR1.Parameters.Add("Confirm", false);

pipeline1.Commands.Add(myCommandR1);

try
{
   //execute script        
   pipeline1.Invoke();
 } catch (Exception e) {
   mw.WriteLog("Exception of type " + e.GetType().ToString() + " was thrown during execution of powershell command : " + e.Message);
   return;
 } finally {
   //close runspace
   runspace.Close();
 }
```

And that's my environnement resumed :

- windc => Domain controller
- app => server where the c# app is running
- admin => admin account of the domain
- appsuser => account that runs the app

If I run the program from the server app logged as appsuser I get the following error :
Exception of type System.Management.Automation.CmdletInvocationException was thrown during execution of powershell command : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.

If I run the powershell command directly from the server app logged as appsuser, it works

If I run the program from the server app logged as admin, it works => That is what tends me to think it's not anything related with the AD Web service, or anything to install (RSAT) on my app server.

That would leave only rights, but then it shouldn't work as appsuser in Powershell neither... So I'm stuck for the moment trying to figure out what rights my account is missing to execute Powershell commands via code.

Answers to Gabriel Luci :

Firewall : No, and since it's working from powershell directly I don't believe that something might be blocking the user on the network level (or don't see how direct Powershell would pass)

Reason for doing that : I've inherited of what was in place when I arrived, and we have a lot of programs available for non admin users to make actions on AD somehow (lock/unlock accounts, reset passwords, change group memberships etc...). At the moment the user on witch all of those programs are running has way too much privileges (they could change the password of domain admin if they tricked it a bit... And since we're a school... Well, we've been lucky so far !). And I'm trying to set up a user with the minimum rights to be able to do just what he's supposed to do.
So my original objective was to make it work without touching the programs themselves (since they work), but I have to admit that your proposition seems way more practical than trying to call Powershell (the old "developer" didn't had any programming background, so I guess he was more prone to use Powershell since he knew that).
I'll search a bit and test what you proposed, at least I hope I can get a cleaner error message than "server not found".

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a firewall running on your computer that is blocking access for only that user?

Also, are those different accounts on different domains?

As a side note: calling PowerShell commands from C#, in my experience, is painful. Do you have a reason for doing it that way? Or is that just the only way you know?

This can be come far more easily in C# using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace (you will have to add that reference to your project):

```cs
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, "GrpLanguageFrench");
group.Members.Remove(ctx, IdentityType.Name, "MazMa");
```

That may not solve your network issues, but it will make your code easier to maintain.

Comment: I've tested your code, now the error is a System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapException
With message : The connection cannot be established

The machine is in the domain, and a System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name gives me the DOMAIN\USERNAME as I would expect

Comment: Are all your accounts on the same domain? (it connects to the user's domain by default) You can try using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see what IP it's trying to connect to (right-click on the process -> Properties -> TCP/IP tab)

Comment: Yes everything is on the same domain.
If I check with process explorer nothing shows in the TCP/IP tab with the appsuser.
If I do the same test with the old user the name of my DC shows correctly (test done on the same machine)

Comment: Yeah, that makes me think it's a software firewall on your computer. Is Windows Firewall running? Or do you have antivirus software that has a builtin firewall?

Comment: Windows Firewall was on, but I took it off and the problem is still the same (but it's on for the user who works as well).
And no antivirus software other than Windows Defender

Comment: Is the esception thrown right away, or does it sit there doing nothing for a while before it finally throws the exception?

Comment: Then something is definitely blocking it. If it's just not accessible, I would expect a timeout (it would sit there waiting until it gives up waiting). But if the exception is thrown immediately, then something immediately closed the connection.

Comment: Just found out that when the program is started from a network drive it throws the error, but if I start it from C: it works as it should. But with the old account it works even from the network drive.